# Intercepting injection

Tags: c#-4.0, ninject, ninject-2

I am injecting repositories into a class, and once I've injected the repositories, I'm assigning my context to each of the repositories so I have my unit of work.

What I'm trying to figure out is, is there a way for me to automatically assign my Unit of Work to each repository as I inject it so that a developer doesn't have to consider this when setting up their code. I've already got my unit of work configured in my base class, the one the developer will be inheriting from.

Can I do something like;

```
Bind<I>().To<S>().WhenInjectedInto<IBaseClass>( i,b => { i.UnitOfWork = b.UnitOfWork });
```

But not have to repeat that pattern every time?

**[UPDATE]**
I'm looking at ways to figure out if Ninject is injecting and what from into, 
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception

I'm trying to look through the tests to see if this is far off base. Any recommendations?

Comment: I've developed all the other parts of this, and now have the situation where whenever I inject a repository into the class, I have to assign it's unit of work and then potentially call a method on it. I'd like to make this an implicit part of injection an IRepository into an IObjectIGuaranteeHasUoW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way would be to inject the context into the repositoies using constructor injection. In a web project you can use InRequestScope for the context binding. For a WPF/WinForms/Console application have a look at Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope. You can define that a single context is used for all dependencies of you `IBaseClass`.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it made me reconsider the design,and what I was getting from it.I'm using the repositories in a given request(MVC3),what I couldn't fathom from examples I've looked at is HOW the repositories got the same unit of work to "work" from.So, my thought was that my handler class held this,and would pass it on to any repositories. Changing the repository(base class)to be responsible for grabbing its own UoW is really no different,and everything is InRequestScope. Thank-you.